# Need a better way to fill values from req.body into a model

Tags: node.js, express, mongoose

I am creating a webapp using the following stack:

- Node
- Express
- MongoDB
- Mongoose

I have structured the app into a MVC structure. In the app I need to get create (post) and update (put) data values which I get from res.body and copy them to Mongoose Model. For example I am doing the following:

Mongoose Model:

```
let mongoose = require('mongoose');

let customerPaymentType = mongoose.Schema({
  type: { type: String, required: true, unique: true}
},
{
  timestamps: true
}
);

module.exports = mongoose.model('CustomerPaymentType', customerPaymentType);
```

Controller (Only a part):

```
let mongoose = require('mongoose');
let CustomerPaymentType = mongoose.model('CustomerPaymentType');

class CustomerPaymentTypeController {
  constructor(){}

  create(req, res){
    let customerPaymentType = new CustomerPaymentType();
    this._setCustomerPaymentType(req.body, customerPaymentType);
    customerPaymentType.save(error=>{
      if (error) res.send(error);
      res.json({
        message: 'Customer payment type successfully created',
        customerPaymentType:{_id: customerPaymentType._id}
      });
    });
  }

  //private methods
  _setCustomerPaymentType(rawCustomerPaymentType, customerPaymentType){
    if (typeof rawCustomerPaymentType.type !== 'undefined') customerPaymentType.type = rawCustomerPaymentType.type.trim();
  }
}

module.exports = CustomerPaymentTypeController;
```

In this model there is only one field, thus populating the model with the data from the req.body in the controller file is easy. But I have other models with more than 30 fields, and it is taking long time to populate them. Is there any easier way to deal with repopulating a model, similar to one present in Ruby on Rails?

Comment: If you are using a mongoose model, you should be able to just do `new CustomerPaymentType(req.body);` and it will populate everything (assuming you are passing a JSON object in the body)

Comment: @DaveV What about mass assignment vulnerability?

Comment: Since this is in your `create` method, and you are making a new `CustomerPaymentType` each time, you won't have anything overwritten, it will create a new document in Mongo each time.